# I have a CSS menu using the following CSS. What is the best way to center the whole menu on the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS menu using the following CSS.  What is the best way to center the whole menu on the page?

How can I make the menu items appear at the center? It is now appearing in the left.

```css
ul#css3menu1{
 margin:0;list-style:none;padding:0;background-color:#dedede;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#5f5f5f;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;font-size:0;z-index:999;position:relative;display:inline-block;zoom:1;
 *display:inline;}
ul#css3menu1 li{
 display:block;white-space:nowrap;font-size:0;float:left;}
* html ul#css3menu1 li a{
 display:inline-block;}
ul#css3menu1>li{
 margin:0;}
ul#css3menu1 a:active, ul#css3menu1 a:focus{
 outline-style:none;}
ul#css3menu1 a{
 display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font:bold 14px "Arial Black",Gadget,sans-serif;color:#7f8184;text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;cursor:pointer;padding:9px 10px 9px 10px;background-color:#b7e5e2;background-image:url("mainbk.png");background-repeat:repeat;background-position:0 0;border-width:0 0 0 1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#C0C0C0;}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed{
 background-color:#7accc6;border-color:#C0C0C0;border-style:solid;color:#ffffff;text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;background-image:url("mainbk.png");background-position:0 100px;text-decoration:none;}
ul#css3menu1 > label.switch{
 display:none;cursor:pointer;width:25px;height:20px;padding:9px 10px 9px 10px;}
ul#css3menu1 > label.switch:before{
 content:"";position:absolute;display:block;height:4px;width:25px;border-radius:4px;background:#7f8184;-moz-box-shadow:0 8px #7f8184, 0 16px #7f8184;-webkit-box-shadow:0 8px #7f8184, 0 16px #7f8184;box-shadow:0 8px #7f8184, 0 16px #7f8184;}
ul#css3menu1 > label.switch:hover:before{
 background:#ffffff;-moz-box-shadow:0 8px #ffffff, 0 16px #ffffff;-webkit-box-shadow:0 8px #ffffff, 0 16px #ffffff;box-shadow:0 8px #ffffff, 0 16px #ffffff;}
ul#css3menu1 > .switchbox{
 display:none;}
ul#css3menu1 li.topfirst>a{
 border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;-moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0;}
ul#css3menu1 li.toplast>a{
 border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;-moz-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;-webkit-border-radius:0;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 ul#css3menu1 > li {
  position: initial;}
 ul#css3menu1 ul .submenu,ul#css3menu1 li > ul {
  left: 0; right:auto; top: 100%;}
 ul#css3menu1 .submenu,ul#css3menu1 ul,ul#css3menu1 .column {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;padding-right: 0;width: 100% !important;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 403px) {
 ul#css3menu1 {
  width: 100%;}
 ul#css3menu1 > li {
  display: none !important;  position: relative;  width: 100% !important;}
 ul#css3menu1 > label.switch,ul#css3menu1 .switchbox:checked ~ li {
  display: block !important;}
}
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle of the menu & css?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `float` option, and `margin` or `padding` can help you in aligning your content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to align your entire page to the center this will help you-

First add your entire content in a div, for example

```
<div id="entire_page">
<!--the rest of the content-->
</div>
```

and then add the following to your css

```
#entire_page{
width:1000px; /*you can change these as you wish*/ 
height:1000px;
margin:auto; /*this aligns the page to the center even if you zoom out*/
}
```